# PKCS11_MODULE path to a file

Tags: python, pkcs#11, nitrokey

I am working on a test program using the Nitrokey HSM:

```
import pkcs11

lib = pkcs11.lib(os.environ['PKCS11_MODULE'])
token = lib.get_token(token_label='smartcard')
    with token.open() as session:

print(session)
```

Question: what can be the pkcs11 library file name? I guessed `opensc-hsm.so`, and defined PKCS11_MODULE to that path, but was not successful.
So, what can be the name of a pkcs11 library to be loaded?
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

According to this [pkcs11 page](https://python-pkcs11.readthedocs.io/en/latest/opensc.html#using-with-smartcard-hsm-nitrokey-hsm) on Nitrokey HSM, the standard OpenSC module can be used:

> The OpenSC PKCS #11 module is opensc-pkcs11.so.

Alternative is to use the HSM smart card vendor's module `libsc-hsm-pkcs11.so`:

- Code: https://github.com/CardContact/sc-hsm-embedded
- Documentation: https://github.com/CardContact/sc-hsm-embedded/wiki/PKCS11

For more information please look at these:

- https://github.com/OpenSC/OpenSC/wiki/SmartCardHSM
- https://www.smartcard-hsm.com/opensource.html
- https://www.smartcard-hsm.com/support.html

Answer (score 0):

At least the Nitrokey Pro can be used with `opensc-pkcs11.so`.